# bash: how to implement the output of 'wc -l' as an argument to another script

Tags: bash

I have a script: 'analysis.pl' where the number of lines in a separate file are required as an input argument:

```
perl ./analysis.pl max=[input number of lines in separate file]
```

It would be very useful if I could give the output of 'wc -l separate_file' as input to the perl script.

```
max=`wc -l NRL.txt`
echo $max
perl ./analysis.pl max=$max
```

The problem is that wc -l gives the number of lines and the file name which returns an error as the argument can only take one input....

```
perl ./analysis.pl max=150000 separate_file ####error
```

So how can I get wc -l to only return the number of lines and not the file name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when passing file as standard input wc doesn't echo filename

```
wc -l < NRL.txt
```

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware about this issue. Can you give me a hint where to read about the difference in output if we use `cmd file` and `cmd < file`?

Comment: in `cmd file`, file is an argument, many commands accept a list of filenames  (ls, cp, mv, grep, etc.) whereas using `cmd < file`, cmd has no arguments and standard input is redirected from file, as when used in a pipe to process output

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this specifically, but one way is to pipe the output of wc to awk and pull the number out of the output of wc:

```
max=`wc -l NRL.txt | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: Some other ways for doing the same, `wc -l NRL.txt | sed 's/ .*//'` OR `wc -l NRL.txt | tr -d 'a-z. '` OR `wc -l NRL.txt | cut -d' ' -f1` OR `a=$(wc -l NRL.txt ) && echo ${a% *}`